# How to improve uiimage detail quality? (too blurry)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

These UIImages are all a bit blurry when the detail is EDIT: more complex.
Can anyone advise me on this one?

I have already tried using CGRectIntegral and the images are always the same size of the uiimageview frame.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "detail is higher"?

Comment: What dimensions does your example image have, what size is it displayed on? Does the effect you describe occur on retina displays and or non retina displays? Is the top-left-corner of that image displayed on a integer coordinate (that is, 1,1 but not 0.5, 0.5)?

Comment: for example, you can see in the first image (my splash screen non retina) with the frame (0,0,320,480) and the dots inside the circle are very blurry. And in the last two images, the rounded corners are a bit blurry as well @BrunoKoga

Comment: @Till I think I answered your questions as well.

Comment: What resolution or format of file do you guys use in order to improve image's look?

Comment: PNG would be the most efficient while keeping the original quality. The term resolution (as in DPI) in this case makes no sense as we are talking about displayed graphics, not printed graphics. Make sure the dimensions (in pixel) of your image exactly match those you are using to display it. Note that the coordinate system of iOS devices is using the unit "points". On a non-retina device, 1 point = 1 pixel. On a retina device, 1 point = 2 pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion:

You should always try to keep the same frame in the real image and the imageview. Same pixel size (width and height)

You can use CGRectIntegral to arrange some minor mismatches. (Fixing the odd placing of the images for instance)

You should use file type .png and keep dpis at 72 at least.

If you want to scale the image for a bigger format you should scale it using the vector of the image or if that is not possible scale it and keep 72 dpis minimum

Comment: the DPI setting is irrelevant. All that matters is pixel dimensions and that you are sizing it to match in the software.